# Using bash return depending on return status of last command executed within a function

Tags: function

I have the following bash function that returns `0` when tho variable `verbos` is defined. Have read the bash manual which says that when return command return `N`, the `N` is omitted, the return status is that of the last command executed within the function.

How can I use only return at the end, taking the value of N, depending on the return status of `[ -n vb ]`?

```
tesverbos  ()
 {
  vb="${verbos+vbset}"  

  if [ -n "$vb" ]; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
 }
```

Comment: `test -z "$vb" && return 1`. I see no issues with your version either. It's OK to have 100500 return statements in your function if needed. You can also replace `return 0` with `:` (yes, semicolon) or `true`.

Comment: would this be equivalent  `test -z "$vb" ; return`  ?

Comment: Actually, `test -z "$vb"` will work. A single statement without any returns, so instead of five line you have just this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```bash
tesverbos  ()
 {
  vb="${verbos+vbset}"  

  test -n "$vb"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use only `return` at the end, taking the value of N, depending on the return status of `[ -n vb ]`?

```
[ -n "$vb" ]
return
```

Or, if the test is the last command in the function, omit the `return` entirely.